# The meaning of $\min()$ in an inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am working on a problem but I am stuck because I do not know how to interpret this part of the problem:

$\varepsilon$ is a positive real number. $x, x_0,$ and $y_0$ are real numbers.

$$ |x-x_{0}|<\min \left(\frac{ \varepsilon  }{2(|y_{0}|+1)},1\right) $$

The rest of the problem includes another inequality to prove a third inequality. I am stuck because I do not know how to interpret the "$\min ( )$" part of this inequality. This is for a first year calculus course - second week.

Comment: Reads rather straightforwardly to me: show that that bit on the left is smaller than either 1 or $\frac{\varepsilon  }{2(|y_{0}|+1)}$, whichever of the two is smaller...

Comment: (continued from @J.M.'s comment) which, in this case, is the same as saying that the bit on the left is smaller than *both* $1$ *and* $\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to interpret it as two inequalities: $|x - x_0| < 1$ *and* $|x-x_0| < \frac{ \varepsilon  }{2(|y_{0}|+1)}$.  If this is an assumption, then you can use either inequality as needed.  If it is what you are trying to prove, then just prove both inequalities.

Answer (score 4):

The min means take the minimum of the arguments.  Generally, $\epsilon$ is expected to be quite a small positive number.  Proofs that there is an acceptable delta sometimes fail when $\epsilon$ gets large.  So we calculate an acceptable delta assuming $\epsilon$ is small (which depends upon $\epsilon$), then put a hard upper limit (here $1$) to handle the case if $\epsilon$ gets large.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have explained what it is being used for here; I'd like to explain just $\min$.

$\min$ is a function, which happens to be part of an inequality here. You could write $\min$ as a piecewise function definition:

$$
\min(a,b) = \begin{cases}
a &\text{if } a ≤ b \\
b &\text{if } b ≤ a
\end{cases}
$$

It is also sometimes written $\min\{a, b\}$, meaning to take the minimum element of the *set* $\{a, b\}$ (which could have more or less than 2 elements).

Answer (score 2):

Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary it is possible that $\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}>1$, while the proof wants to assert $|x-x_0|$ is small.

Therefore this reads as $|x-x_0|$ is less than the minimal number between $1$ and $\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}>1$. In a sense this is a "cutoff" to ensure the value is at most $1$.